# I want the custom filter to the purpose of searching to find the table's data

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

My Controller:

```
public class SortOfContactListController {
    public List<Contact> ContactListTable {get; set;}
    public String ExpressionOfSort = 'name';
    public String DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';

    public SortOfContactListController() {
        ContactListTable = new List<Contact>();
    }
    public String ExpressionSort {
        get {
            return ExpressionOfSort;
        }
        set {
            If(value == ExpressionOfSort) {
                DirectionOfSort = (DirectionOfSort == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            }
            else {
                DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';
                ExpressionOfSort = value;
            }
        }

    }

    public String getDirectionOfSort() {
        If(ExpressionOfSort == Null || ExpressionOfSort == '') {
            return 'DESC';
        }
        else {
            return DirectionOfSort;
        }
    }

    public void setDirectionOfSort(String value) {
        DirectionOfSort = value;
    }

    public List<Contact>getContacts() {
        return ContactListTable;
    }

    public PageReference ViewData() {
        String FullSortExpression = ExpressionOfSort + ' ' + DirectionOfSort;
        system.debug('ExpressionOfSort:::::'+ExpressionOfSort);
        system.debug(DirectionOfSort);

        //String Queryitem = new String();
       String Queryitem = 'SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name != Null ORDER BY ' + FullSortExpression + ' Limit 1000';

        ContactListTable = DataBase.query(Queryitem);
        system.debug(ContactListTable);
        return Null;
    }

}
```

My VisualPage:

```
<apex:page controller="SortOfContactListController" action="{!ViewData}"  >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="ListOfContacts With Accounts"/>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactListTable}" var="contact" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(ContactListTable))}" id="cmdsort">

                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">   
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Contact Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC', '▼', '▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputLink value="/{!contact.Id}" target="_blank">{!contact.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Account.Name}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Account Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Account.Name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Account.Name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Phone{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Phone',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Phone" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Email{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Email',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Email" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing City{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingCity',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="MailingCity" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCountry}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Country{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingCountry',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="MailingCountry" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Postal Code{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingPostalCode',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="MailingPostalCode" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>            
        </apex:pageBlock>        
    </apex:form>
```

So I want the filter function done by all column by clicking the search button. Thank you 
Mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer of my question is,

Apex Controller:

public class SortOfContactListController {

```
public List<Contact> ContactListTable {get; set;}
public String ExpressionOfSort = 'name';
public String DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';
public List<Contact> ContactResults {get; set;}

public SortOfContactListController() {
    ContactListTable = new List<Contact>();
    ContactResults = new List<Contact>();
}


public string ContactName {
    get;
    set;
}

 public string Phone {
    get;
    set;
}

 public string AccountName {
    get;
    set;
}
```

public string Birthdate {
        get;
        set;
    }

```
public string BirthdateMIN {
    get;
    set;
} 

public string BirthdateMAX {
    get;
    set;   
}

public string Email {
    get;
    set;
}

public string MailingCity {
    get;
    set;
}

public string MailingCountry {
    get;
    set;
}

public string MailingPostalCode {
    get;
    set;
} 


public String ExpressionSort {
    get {
        return ExpressionOfSort;
    }
    set {
        If(value == ExpressionOfSort) {
            DirectionOfSort = (DirectionOfSort == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        }
        else {
            DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';
            ExpressionOfSort = value;
        }
    }

}

public String getDirectionOfSort() {
    If(ExpressionOfSort == Null || ExpressionOfSort == '') {
        return 'DESC';
    }
    else {
        return DirectionOfSort;
    }
}

public void setDirectionOfSort(String value) {
    DirectionOfSort = value;
}

public List<Contact>getContacts() {
    return ContactListTable;
}

public PageReference ViewData() {
    String FullSortExpression = ExpressionOfSort + ' ' + DirectionOfSort;
    system.debug('ExpressionOfSort:::::'+ExpressionOfSort);
    system.debug(DirectionOfSort);

   String Queryitem = ' SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Birthdate, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name != Null ORDER BY ' + FullSortExpression +' Limit 1000';
   system.debug(Queryitem);

    ContactListTable = DataBase.query(Queryitem);
    system.debug(ContactListTable);
    return Null;
}

public PageReference Search() {
String searchquery = ' SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Birthdate, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name != Null';
system.debug(searchquery);
String condition = '';
if (ContactName != null && ContactName != '') {
    condition += ' and Name LIKE \'' + ContactName + '%\'';
    }

if (AccountName != null && AccountName != '') {
    condition += ' and Account.Name LIKE \'' + AccountName + '%\'';
    }

if (BirthdateMIN != Null && BirthdateMIN !='') {
    condition += ' and Birthdate >= ' + BirthdateMIN;
    system.debug(BirthdateMIN); 
   }

if (BirthdateMAX != Null && BirthdateMAX != '') {

       condition += ' and Birthdate <= ' + BirthdateMAX;
       system.debug(BirthdateMAX);  
    }

   // system.debug(condition);

if (Phone != null && Phone != '') {
    condition += ' and Phone LIKE \'' + Phone + '%\'';
    }

if (Email != null && Email != '') {
    condition += ' and Email LIKE \'' + Email + '%\'';
    }

if (MailingCountry != null && MailingCountry != '') {
     condition += ' and MailingCountry LIKE \'' + MailingCountry + '%\'';
     }

if (MailingCity != null &&  MailingCity != '') {
     condition += ' and MailingCity LIKE \'' + MailingCity + '%\'';
     }

if (MailingPostalCode != null && MailingPostalCode != '') {
     condition += ' and MailingPostalCode LIKE \'' + MailingPostalCode + '%\'';
     }

if (condition != '') {
searchquery += condition;
System.debug(' searchquery:::::::: '+searchquery);

ContactResults = DataBase.query(searchquery);
system.debug(' ContactResults::::::::::: '+ContactResults);

}
return Null;

}
```

}

My visual Page is:

```
<apex:form >

    <apex:sectionHeader title="List Of Contacts With Accounts"/>

    <apex:PanelGrid columns="1" id="panel" cellpadding="2">

        <apex:outputLabel value="Contact Name: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="ContactName" value="{!ContactName}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="AccountName" value="{!AccountName}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Birth DateMIN(YYYY-MM-DD): "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="BirthdateMIN" value="{!BirthdateMIN}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Birth DateMAX(YYYY-MM-DD): "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="BirthdateMAX" value="{!BirthdateMAX}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Phone: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="Phone" value="{!Phone}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Email: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="Email" value="{!Email}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Mailing City: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="MailingCity" value="{!MailingCity}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Mailing Country: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="MailingCountry" value="{!MailingCountry}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Mailing Postal Code: "></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText id="MailingPostalCode" value="{!MailingPostalCode}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"></apex:inputText>           

        <div></div>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Search}" value="search" rerender="pageblock"></apex:commandButton>

    <apex:pageBlock id="pageblock" >
        <apex:messages ></apex:messages>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Results" id="results" columns="1" collapsible="true">   
             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactResults}" var="searchoption" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(ContactResults))}" id="searchinfo">

                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.Name}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.Account.Name}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.Phone}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.Email}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.Birthdate}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.MailingCity}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.MailingCountry}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!searchoption.MailingPostalCode}"/>

             </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>            
    </apex:pageBlock>


    <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactListTable}" var="contact" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(ContactListTable))}" id="cmdsort">

             <apex:column >
                 <apex:facet name="header">   
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Contact Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC', '▼', '▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!contact.Id}" target="_blank">{!contact.Name}</apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Account.Name}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Account Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Account.Name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Account.Name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Birthdate}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Birth Date{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Birthdate',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Birthdate" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Phone{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Phone',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Phone" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Email{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Email',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Email" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing City{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingCity',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="MailingCity" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCountry}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Country{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingCountry',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="MailingCountry" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Postal Code{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingPostalCode',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="MailingPostalCode" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:PanelGrid>       
</apex:form>
```